# Gazebo with controller

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, sdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know there have been a few posts on SDF vs URDF for gazebo, but I'm still not sure I know which to use.

It particularly interests me when I see this in the terminal (running `pr2_empty_world.launch` ):

```
Warning [parser.cc:348] Gazebo SDF has no gazebo element
Warning [parser.cc:291] DEPRECATED GAZEBO MODEL FILE
On July 1st, 2012, this formate will no longer by supported
Convert your files using the gzsdf command line tool
You have been warned!
```

So, if I want to go to SDF, then I cannot run a robot controller, or at least cannot use [robot_description](http://answers.ros.org/question/33628/load-sdf-model-into-robot_description/) param required to run a controller.

But if I stick with URDF, then it's deprecated? If I could input Collada files or SDF with the robot_description param, I think it would help.

I see the reference to a collada converter [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4330) but haven't seen anything on it since this ticket that's over a year old.

Has it been maintained?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41294/gazebo-with-controller/) by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 682 on 2012-08-13

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) on 2012-08-13**:
Hello, I have a simmechnaics file( meshes are in stl format). I converted it to a urdf file then to a xacro file, I got the same warnings( gazebo_worlds/empty_world_paused). I am not whether these warnings affect my simulation in gazebo.

**Comment by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on 2012-08-13**:
Was the conversion straightforward? I know there are urdf->collada (or stl I assume) but didn't know of the reverse. Thanks

**Comment by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) on 2012-08-14**:
hello, yes the conversion was straightforward, I used simmechanics_to_urdf package but I got an tf exception error then I used another version of simmechanics_to_urdf package, no problem occured. But when i launch gazebo and my robot's urdf, I got error described by you, .dae is collada format i gue

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-08-26**:
Hi. i am a new user of gazebo with ROS and I get the similar warnings when i launched gazebo. May i know what should I do about the warnings? In addition, my gazebo often terminates unexpectedly, could these warnings be the reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

URDF will not be deprecated without a way to load it in gazebo, so no worries there.  We've started the process of adding URDF parsing in gazebo, more details to come.  At least for now (in Fuerte), there will not be any interrupted support for URDF spawning in gazebo.

Thanks,
John

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on 2012-08-17**:
Thanks. Might I ask if you know what ever happened with the ticket I referenced?

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-08-17**:
hi, if the converter is broken, please file a new trac ticket against it?  thanks,

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2012-12-29**:
@hsu is there already update about URDF parsing?

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-07-16**:
I am new to ROS/gazebo and I thought that URDF was the historical format for ROS/gazebo and that gazebo had started to move away from URDF and to SDF. Am I wrong?